# MySQL Create Trigger Keywords

Tags: mysql, triggers, keyword

I know that in triggers you have the keywords NEW and OLD to refer to the entry that is being, or was, inserted into the table to which the trigger is bound. Are there any other keywords? I'm looking for one specifically that reference's the table that the trigger is bound to (like CUR_TABLE, or something); this way I can copy the trigger and apply it to several tables with different names and not need to alter the body of the trigger? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're in that trigger, then the trigger knows what table to use.. I'm confused about your question, though.

Comment: i want to use a select statement inside of the trigger function like (SELECT `key_name` FROM CUR_TABLE) or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL cannot be used in triggers. For the trigger to exist, then the developer already knows what table he's in - so the table name should theoretically be hard coded.

If you are generating triggers, from say a stored procedure, you can generate them with variable table names - but cannot execute them (so you would have to take the result of the stored procedure and execute it separately).

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in MySQL. You may do a small PHP script that generates the code for each "table name" in an array :)